# Kernel SVM, select important features in R

Tags: r, kernel, svm, polynomials

I have a matrix with 1000*700 dimension with binary column as classification. I have used Ksvm in kernlab to fit a polynomial model on my data. ROC and precession-Recall curve showed the polynomial model works better than others. I am interested to extract the most important features that determine the model sensitivity and specificity. General speaking, what are the most important features in model?
So I am using the following command to extract the features but I am not sure if I am right.

```
svp <- ksvm(as.matrix(xtrain),as.factor(ytrain),type="C-svc",kernel="poly")

weight <- colSums(coef(svp)[[1]] * xtrain[SVindex(svp),])

w <- sort( weight, decreasing=T)

w <- data.frame(w)
```

So the top max weight are the most important features.

Please let me know if I am right or wrong?

Thanks

Morteza

Comment: I think this question belongs to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Not really. I only want to know what features are significantly contribute in the model.